# How to wait for an ImageView in xml to finish loading

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I want to create a title screen for an Android app. The screen is a simple XML file with an image in it. Basically the screen will show until some other stuff finishes loading, upon which the screen will change to the app content. The problem is, many time the image in the XML doesn't appear at all - all I get is a blank xml page, and afterwards the app loads. I assumeit's because loading the image is done async or something. I tried to use Thread.sleep, which proved to be a bad idea.
Anyone has an idea how to get this to work?
Thanks!
The main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

The main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    <do some stuff>
    start_other_activity_with_different_xml();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got found the answer faster than I expected. For my purposes, what I'm looking for is a splash screen, and a good explanation of how to create one can be found here:    http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/